# Zend framework 2 - cannot set the 'from' field when sending a email

Tags: php, gmail, zend-framework2

I try to send a email using ZF2

```
    $message = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
    $message->setBody('This is the body');
    $message->setFrom('myemail@mydomain.com');
    $message->addTo('someone@somedomain.com');
    $message->setSubject('Test subject');

    $smtpOptions = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions();

    $smtpOptions->setHost('smtp.gmail.com')
        ->setConnectionClass('login')
        ->setName('smtp.gmail.com')
        ->setConnectionConfig(array(
            'username' => 'admin@mydomain.com',
            'password' => 'mypassword',
            'ssl' => 'tls',
            'port' => '123',
        ));

    $transport = new \Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp($smtpOptions);
    $transport->send($message);
```

I expect the sender to be 'myemail@mydomain.com' but it's always 'admin@mydomain.com.com'

How can I do to fix this ? What I've done wrong ?

**EDIT :**

I also tried with setSender() with the same results

Comment: Search all your project for `admin@mydomain.com.com` - chances are, you won't find it. If that's so, then your server configuration is set up to simply overwrite the specific mail-header before sending.

Comment: It's only at one place, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code of **\Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp** and **\Zend\Mail\Message** classes it seems to me that you're doing right; the *send* function (**Smtp** class) first connects to the smtp server and then prepares the message. One of the tasks is getting the *from* address, the one causing you problems. This is the code:

```
protected function prepareFromAddress(Message $message)
{
    $sender = $message->getSender();
    if ($sender instanceof Address\AddressInterface) {
        return $sender->getEmail();
    }

    $from = $message->getFrom();
    if (!count($from)) { // Per RFC 2822 3.6
        throw new Exception\RuntimeException(sprintf(
            '%s transport expects either a Sender or at least one From address in the Message; none provided',
            __CLASS__
        ));
    }

    $from->rewind();
    $sender = $from->current();
    return $sender->getEmail();
}
```

I haven't tested by myself, can you check that it gets the *from* from the **$message->getFrom();**? Or maybe it gets it from the **$sender->getEmail();**?

One thing you can try is to use the **setSender()** instead of **setFrom()** to set the 'myemail@mydomain.com' address when you define the message. I don't understand very well the difference between them, but looking at the **prepareFromAddress** function, it seems that you could use it to place the *from* address.

Comment: I already tried, unsuccessfully, to use setSender(). If the sender is set, it take the sender otherwise, it take the from. I check the headers and the data is correctly sent to gmail the server